# Omegle changing behavior

Tags: website

I am not sure if the question that I am going to ask is suitable for this particular site. I would be glad to listen to recommendation of any other stackoverflow site ,where this question would be more suitable.

So a few days ago , I logged in to omegle.com and by default Omegle was connecting with the language of the country I live in and I could connect with people speaking that language or living in that country. However , since yesterday night the functionality seems to have changed somehow and it seems that on choosing a language I am not getting connected to language speakers or people from the country where the language is spoken but rather it is translating both the messages of mine and the other participant into the chosen language.

Does anyone know anything about this issue ? Is there a setting by which I can restore to the previous functionality ?

Comment: You can select a language in the settings or at the top right. You may have to view the desktop version if you're on mobile

Comment: I think/fear this may be off-topic, see https://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Thanks ,I was using the website in desktop....changing the language did not work that way

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Thank you , any site which is relevant for this ?